# Facing problems while debugging python file which also includes html form file in Visual Studio 2019 IDE. Using XAMPP for displaying the html values

Tags: html, python-3.x, xampp, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

[python file including html file in visual studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0ijg.png)

As shown in the above pic, I have started the debug in the 7 line by putting breakpoints in it.
But in the output window it's not showing the desired output i.e firstname value which I have inserted in the html form.
And I'm using XAMPP server to display the html forms values in python.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

You do not write any `print` method to return the value. The output window only show the return value you specify and is not obligated to display the parameter value automatically under the code. If you want to display the value of a parameter, that is the job of [the autos window or watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2019) under debug mode. If you want to show the value to the output window, you should use `print` to return its value.

So you have to use the `print` method to return parameter value to the output window.

use these:

```
import cgi,cgitb

form=cgi.FieldStorage()

first_name=form.getvalue('first_name')

print(first_name)

last_name=form.getvalue('last_name')

print(last_name)

if form.getvalue('gender'):
     gender=form.getvalue('gender')

else:
      gender="Not set"

print(gender)

.....
```